# How can i sent a video,audio,images from android to server

Tags: php, android, wamp

Can anyone give me some info how can i sent a video with large size  from android to server pls ,i have read much info but i dont have find nothing ,how is the best way to sent video ,audio or images but with a large size.I have seen here in this website some info but are so old some info using the http client with multipart but all the souce code are deprecated and the http client is removet in api 23 please is so important for me thank you 
i have create a simple app and record the video save in phone and i want to sent in server for the moment im using wamp and in the server side use a simple PHP code that with recive the video and save in a folder

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this well explained tutorial 
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

I use my own businness i can upload file bigger than 1gb

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import com.thatsit.App;
import com.thatsit.data.model.Message;
import com.thatsit.data.model.MessageDataModel;
import com.thatsit.data.model.RemoteOperation;
import com.thatsit.interfaces.OnRespondListener;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by Marco on 29/06/2015.
 */
/**
 * Uploading the file to server
 * */
public class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    private static final String TAG = UploadFileToServer.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DISPLAY_UPLOAD_PERCENTAGE_ACTION = "com.yourapp.app.UPLOAD_PERCENTAGE";
    public static final String EXTRA_MSG_ID = "message_id";
    public static final String EXTRA_PERCENTAGE = "percent";

    private OnRespondListener mListener;
    private long totalSize;
    private Message message;
    public UploadFileToServer(Message message){
        this.message = message;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        //TODO implement progressbar interface
        //progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(mListener == null){
            mListener = new OnRespondListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccessResponse(String TAG, String resp) {
                    Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000));
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(String TAG, String Error) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Error response " + Error);
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
//        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
//        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        // Notify UI with broadcast message
        Intent i = new Intent(DISPLAY_UPLOAD_PERCENTAGE_ACTION);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_MSG_ID, message.getId());
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_PERCENTAGE, progress[0]);
        App.getContext().sendBroadcast(i);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = "";
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        //String fileName = CommonServerAdd.MEDIA_UPLOAD_URL;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(URI.create(message.getMediaName()));

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + message.getMediaName());
        } else{
            try {
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(CommonServerAdd.MEDIA_UPLOAD_URL);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                //conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty(RemoteOperation.KEY_MEDIA_UPLOAD, message.getMediaName());

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());


                HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // Extra parameters to pass to web server
                postDataParams.put(RemoteOperation.OP_OPERATION_TAG, RemoteOperation.OP_UPLOAD_MEDIA);
                postDataParams.put(MessageDataModel.KEY_SENDER_ID, App.Profile.getUid());
                postDataParams.put(MessageDataModel.KEY_FROM_ME, String.valueOf(message.getFromMe()));
                postDataParams.put(MessageDataModel.KEY_DATA, message.getData());
                postDataParams.put(MessageDataModel.KEY_REMOTE_ID, message.getRemoteId());
                postDataParams.put(MessageDataModel.KEY_TIMESTAMP, String.valueOf(message.getTimestamp()));
                postDataParams.put(MessageDataModel.KEY_REMOTE_TABLE_ID, String.valueOf(message.getId()));
                postDataParams.put(MessageDataModel.KEY_MEDIA_TYPE, String.valueOf(message.getMediaType()));

                for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : postDataParams.entrySet()){
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + entry.getKey() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(entry.getValue());
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                }

                //Adding Parameter media file(audio,video and image)
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\";filename=\""+ message.getMediaName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                long fileLength = sourceFile.length();
                Log.d(TAG,"totalSize= " + fileLength);
                int sentBytes=0;
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    // Publish progress
                    sentBytes += bufferSize;
                    publishProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100 / bytesAvailable));
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }


                // send multipart form data necessary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String ServerResponseString = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + ServerResponseString + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if(serverResponseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    Log.d(TAG,"File Upload Completed.");
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        responseString +=line;
                    }
                }

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG,"MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            //return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block

        return responseString;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            String success = response.getString(RemoteOperation.RESP_SUCCESS);
            if (Integer.parseInt(success) == 1) {
                // return confirm
                mListener.onSuccessResponse(RemoteOperation.OP_MESSAGE_DELIVERED, response.getString("serv_receipt_timestamp"));
            } else {
                mListener.onErrorResponse(RemoteOperation.OP_MESSAGE_DELIVERED, response.getString(RemoteOperation.RESP_ERR_MESSAGE));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mListener.onErrorResponse(RemoteOperation.OP_MESSAGE_DELIVERED, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void setResponseListener(OnRespondListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
/**
 * To test this request send on payload:
 * tag=302&sender_id=5588723e18dd67.58708277&key_from_me=1&data=bla+bla&key_remote_id=55886e677a97d7.22335532&timestamp=12346789&key_tbl_id=20
 *
 * and file to upload on body with var name 'media'
 */
//Log
//Read param as get POST
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/UsersFolder/'."Log_media_upload_request.txt";
file_put_contents($path,$post);
//var_dump($_POST);
// array for final json respone
$response = array(Response::KEY_SUCCESS => 0, Response::KEY_ERROR => 1);

// getting server ip address
//$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// final file url that is being uploaded
//$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'server' . '/' . $target_path;


if (
    !isset($_POST[RemoteOperation::OP_OPERATION_TAG]) ||
    !isset($_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_SENDER_ID])  ||
    !isset($_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_FROM_ME]) ||
    !isset($_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_DATA]) ||
    !isset($_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_REMOTE_ID]) ||
    !isset($_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_TIMESTAMP]) ||
    !isset($_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_DEVICE_TABLE_ID]) ||
    !isset($_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_MEDIA_TYPE]) ||
    !isset($_FILES['media']['name'])
){
    $response[Response::KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE] = "Param error";
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
$operation = $_POST[RemoteOperation::OP_OPERATION_TAG];
$unique_id = $_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_SENDER_ID];
$mediaType = $_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_MEDIA_TYPE];

$mediaName = $_FILES['media']['name'];

//check for user exists
$user = new UserDataModel();
$myUser = new User();

if(!$myUser = $user->getUserByUid($unique_id)){
    $response[Response::KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE] = "User error";
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
$file_upload_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/UsersFolder/' . $unique_id . '/';
$media_url = 'http://www.yourserver.com/UsersFolder' ."/". $unique_id . '/';
switch($mediaType){
    case MediaType::IMAGE_PROFILE_THUMB:
        $target_path = $file_upload_url . 'Profile' .'/'.  basename($_FILES['media']['name']);
        $media_url = $media_url . 'Profile' .'/'.  basename($_FILES['media']['name']);
        break;
    case MediaType::IMAGE:
        $target_path = $file_upload_url . 'Image' .'/'. basename($_FILES['media']['name']);
        $media_url = $media_url . 'Image' .'/'. basename($_FILES['media']['name']);
        break;
    case MediaType::VIDEO:
        $target_path = $file_upload_url . 'Video' .'/'. basename($_FILES['media']['name']);
        $media_url = $media_url . 'Video' .'/'. basename($_FILES['media']['name']);
        break;
    case MediaType::AUDIO:
        $target_path = $file_upload_url . 'Audio' .'/'. basename($_FILES['media']['name']);
        $media_url = $media_url . 'Audio' .'/'. basename($_FILES['media']['name']);
        break;
    default:
        $response[Response::KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE] = "Unknown operation";
        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
        break;
}
try {
    // Throws exception in case file is not being moved
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['media']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        // make error flag true
        $response[Response::KEY_ERROR] = 1;
        $response[Response::KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE] = 'Could not move the file!';
    }else {
        //file moved ok, carry on store message to db
        $mess = new MessageDataModel();
        $mediaSize = filesize($target_path);

        if($mediaType == MediaType::IMAGE_PROFILE_THUMB){
            //Create small thumb
            //Add row to ProfileImageHistory table
            include_once "DatabaseHandler/ProfileImageHistoryDataModel.php";
            $profileImg = new ProfileImageHistoryDataModel();
            if($result = $profileImg->uploadImageProfile($myUser->getId(),$_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_SENDER_ID],$mediaName, $mediaType, $mediaSize, $media_url)){
                // message stored successfully
                $response[Response::KEY_SUCCESS] = 1;
                $response[Response::KEY_ERROR] = 0;
                $response[Response::RESP_SERVER_RECEIPT_TIMESTAMP] = $result;
            } else {
                // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
                $response[Response::KEY_ERROR] = 1;
                $response[Response::KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE] = "Error on store message";
            }
        }else{
            //Store and send message as image Audio or Video
            if ($result = $mess->storeMessage(
                $_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_SENDER_ID],
                $_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_FROM_ME],
                $_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_DATA],
                $_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_REMOTE_ID],
                $_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_TIMESTAMP],
                $_POST[MessageDataModel::KEY_DEVICE_TABLE_ID],
                $mediaName, $mediaType, $mediaSize, $media_url)
            ) {
                // message stored successfully
                $response[Response::KEY_SUCCESS] = 1;
                $response[Response::KEY_ERROR] = 0;
                $response[Response::RESP_SERVER_RECEIPT_TIMESTAMP] = $result;
            } else {
                // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
                $response[Response::KEY_ERROR] = 1;
                $response[Response::KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE] = "Error on store message";
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
    $response[Response::KEY_ERROR] = 1;
    $response[Response::KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE] = "Server exception " . $e->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I will try now hope it will work and thank you if work i will accept the answer

Comment: be careful before you use, you need to change with your needs a lot of var.

Comment: Okej but here need and a database ?

Comment: i use a db to store other information like message from date time etc. but you can skip. I have tested with Advanced Rest client for chrome... If you like please don't forgot to vote tnks

Comment: Yes i have vote and i will accept the answer if this work because now im with phone

Comment: i think i can understand this at all maybe you have this sample in github ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I always use on my own, but if you follow a tut will be very easy

Comment: this code is so hard to understand and i think need to use library please can you see my answer i have edit and maybe you can help thanks